# How to correctly identify html node

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape the price of a product on a webshop, but I struggle to correctly allocate the correct nodes to the price i want to scrape.
The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
"https://www.surfdeal.ch/produkt/2019-aqua-marina-fusion-orange/"%>%
  read_html()%>%
  html_nodes('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount')%>%
  html_text()
```

When executing this code, I do get prices as a result, but not the ones i want (it shows the prices of other produts that are listed beneath.
How can I now correctly identify the node to the price of the product itself (375.-)

Comment: this price is in `span.price` so you could add this to selector `'span.price  span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount'`

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to add this price but I don't know if `rvest` can run `JavaScript`

Comment: adding `span.price` somewhat alters the output, but still doesn't exctract the price i want. But thanks nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

First: I don't know `R`.

This page uses `JavaScript` to add this price in HTML
but I don't know if `rvest` can run `JavaScript`.

But I found this value in `<form data-product_variations="...">` as `JSON`
and I could display prices for all options:

```r
data <- "https://www.surfdeal.ch/produkt/2019-aqua-marina-fusion-orange/" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('form.variations_form.cart') %>%
  html_attr('data-product_variations') %>%
  fromJSON
  
data$display_price  
  
data$regular_price    

data$image$title
```

Result:

```
> data$display_price
[1] 479 375 439 479 479

> data$display_regular_price    
[1] 699 549 629 699 699

> data$image$title
[1] "aqua marina fusion bamboo padddel"   
[2] "aqua marina fusion aluminium padddel"
[3] "aqua marina fusion carbon padddel"   
[4] "aqua marina fusion hibi padddel"     
[5] "aqua marina fusion silver padddel"  

>  colnames(data)
 [1] "attributes"            "availability_html"     "backorders_allowed"   
 [4] "dimensions"            "dimensions_html"       "display_price"        
 [7] "display_regular_price" "image"                 "image_id"             
[10] "is_downloadable"       "is_in_stock"           "is_purchasable"       
[13] "is_sold_individually"  "is_virtual"            "max_qty"              
[16] "min_qty"               "price_html"            "sku"                  
[19] "variation_description" "variation_id"          "variation_is_active"  
[22] "variation_is_visible"  "weight"                "weight_html"          
[25] "is_bookable"           "number_of_dates"       "your_discount"        
[28] "gtin"                  "your_delivery"
```

---

**EDIT:**

To work with page which uses JavaScript you may need other tools - like [phantomjs](https://phantomjs.org/)

[How to Scrape Data from a JavaScript Website with R | R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/12/how-to-scrape-data-from-a-javascript-website-with-r/)